# Chat move messages bug for Mac users

Tags: bug, chat, mac

As a room owner on chat, you can move messages out of the room. To do this, we can click on the Room link in the sidebar and select Move Messages. This results in the following instructions:

[image]

Now on a Mac, <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click  works fine for selecting an entire set of consecutive messages. However, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click doesn't work as OS X interprets it as a right click.

Could this <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-Click functionality also be tied to <kbd>⌘</kbd>-click (Command-click) for OS X users?

Comment: This really is a problem, and it needs to be fixed already.

Comment: Isn't this fixable by just using alt or cmd on OS X?

Comment: @bwoebi Nopers.

Comment: This is a bug with OSX, not Stack Exchange :P

Comment: @ɥʇǝS Nope, it's not a bug, MacOS just works differently from Windows. `ctrl` / `cmd` is accounted for in lots of other places in SE's Javascript, but not here for some reason.

Comment: @fredley My point was Apple shouldn't be redefining everything ;)

Comment: @ɥʇǝS It's been that way for *decades!*

Comment: Boy this is a pain in the neck for moderators. Please, SO, add a Command-click option for us OS X users!

Comment: And a little while later, it turns out that CMD-click does work, on my laptop. I'll have to explore why this didn't work on my Kinesis keyboard.