# Mac users can't move multiple non-consecutive lines of text between chat rooms

Tags: feature-request, support, chat, mac

As a room owner, I occasionally find it necessary to get non-germane content<sup>1</sup> out of a chat room quickly. Fortunately, there's an excellent Move Messages button that works quite well.

I can even move multiple messages at once! Except, well, I use a Mac. And that means I can only move *consecutive* messages in a single action. Everyone *else* can choose nonconsecutive text all willy nilly.

[image: CONTROL KEY! MY NEMESIS!]

Y'see, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click is identical to Right-Click on OS X. It should be trivial to also trigger for <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>-Click, which would be the standard way for mac users to select multiple items.

That'd be swell. Real, swell.

<sub>Incidentially, this is actually a [fairly old dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156494/chat-move-messages-bug-for-mac-users), but the new rules mean that closing this question as a dupe of that old one would be inappropriate. Might I recommend closing the old feature request as a duplicate of *this* question, once it's resolved?</sub>

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I.E. Pony gifs.</sub>

Comment: +1 for freehand circles yaddayadda

Comment: Oh, come on, you can't expect SE to support every obscure toy OS there is...

Comment: -1 You're asking _meta_ to help you censor pony gifs? This is unacceptable. Voting to close as against meta philosophy. ;-)

Comment: Hit us up in the JavaScript chat room in SO chat. ping for @rlemon , he wrote a user script that lets you select a user and bin all his recent messages - I think you'll find that really useful. Being a room that has to deal with a lot of help vampires, newbies trolls etc, we've developed some clever tricks :)

Comment: Can you do Fn+Control+click, out of curiosity?

Comment: @minitechη Negative. Does not work.

Comment: What would the *correct* modifier key be? To select/deselect a single item in a multi-selection, what key does the Mac use for that?

Comment: @balpha The 'correct' way to do things, (at least in the finder), is Command-Click.

Answer (score 2):

I delved into the javascript. All you need to do is replace:

```
else if (a.ctrlKey) b.toggleClass("selected");
```

with

```
else if (a.ctrlKey || a.metaKey) b.toggleClass("selected");
```

Sadly this code is within a private scope, so it can't (easily) be userscripted.